# How to get coordinates of selected word on QWebView

Tags: qtwebview

mighty All,

I have selected the word by QWebPage::SelectNextWord(). 
I just exec the code:
    ui->webView->page()->triggerAction(QWebPage::SelectNextWord);

The question is: how to define coordinates of blue rect of selected word,
any method which allows to solve this (Qt, Windows MDN, jscript,...)

Does anybody know how to do this?

Regards,
Radmir

Answer (score 0):

MDN Api allows to write small script, that solves the task.
Thanks, 
the question is closed.

Radmir